# Fibration with fibre $\mathbb{C}P^\infty$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fibration, eilenberg-maclane-spaces

I have a fibration $F\to E\to B$ where $B$ is a nice space (a compact manifold) and the fibre is $\mathbb{C}P^\infty$, i. e. an Eilenberg–MacLane space $K(\mathbb{Z},2)$. Are there good criteria to check if this fibration is fibre homotopy equivalent to the trivial bundle? (I found [here](https://hrcak.srce.hr/file/110172) something for $K(G,1)$-fibrations)

Comment: Have a look at Lemma 3.4.2 in May's "More Concise Algebraic Topology". It gives criteria on when such a fibration admits a classifying map $B\rightarrow BF$. Obviously if the fibration is homotopically trivial then it does.Conversely if your fibration classifies then you may be able to see that it does not split.

Comment: Thank you! So if I am able to show that $\pi_1(B)$ acts trivially on $\pi_2(F)=\mathbb{Z}$ then I have by the Lemma a classifying map $f:B\to K(\mathbb{Z},3)$ and the fibration is (up to fibre-homotopy equivalence) the pullback of the path space fibration along $f$, right? Now obviously the path space fibration is not homotopically trivial, is it? Hence I need to do something with the pullback …?

Comment: You could either show that $f$ is trivial (for instance if $H^3(B)=0$) in which case the fibration might be splitable, or show that $f$ is non-trivial and then calculate enough cohomology of $E\simeq F_f$ to show that the fibration cannot split.

Comment: Unfortunately, $H^3(B)$ doesn’t vanish. In order to show that $f$ is null-homotopic, my next attempt would be to show that $f^*\alpha=0$ for the $\alpha\in H^3(K(\mathbb{Z},3))$ corresponding to $1$ under the identification $H^3(K(\mathbb{Z},3))= \mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}$. Is there anything known about the map $f$ which I can use?